# Postfix access restrictions

Tags: postfix, restrictions

I use Postfix 2.9.6 from Debian7. Defined some virtual domains, all works fine as expected.

Now I want to restrict incoming emails for one of my domains to accept email if it come from the same domain, or if sender is sasl_authenticated (from other hosted domains on the same server) or incoming mail come from one white-listed domains (about 2-3 domains).

In Postfix configs I see just sender_restrictions and recipient_restriction, but how to control recipient/sender at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can achieve this using only postfix alone. Have a look on 
[postfwd](http://postfwd.org/), there you could set ruleset like:

```
&&TO_PROTECTED_DOMAIN {  recipient_domain=my_protected_domain.tld; };
&&FROM_WHITELIST_DOMAIN { sender_domain=my_protected_domain.tld; \
                          sender_domain=whitelisted1.tld; \
                          sender_domain=whitelisted2.tld; \
                        };

id=PD_01;  &&TO_PROTECTED_DOMAIN; sasl_method =~ (LOGIN|PLAIN);  action=DUNNO
id=PD_02;  &&TO_PROTECTED_DOMAIN; &&FROM_WHITELIST_DOMAIN; action=DUNNO
id=PD_03;  &&TO_PROTECTED_DOMAIN; action=REJECT You're not permitted sending to this domain.
```

Answer (score 3):

Postfix has features to do that called [SMTPD Restriction Classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html). But it's not *convenient* like you write some ACL with `if-then-else`. For this, you can use [postfwd](http://postfwd.org) like the [answer from tomas](https://serverfault.com/a/678172/218590) or [policyD](http://wiki.policyd.org/)

---

Here you put in `main.cf`

```
# define one restrictio class, let's name it 'specialdomain'
smtpd_restriction_classes = specialdomain

# define the restriction for this class
specialdomain = 
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/specialdomain2    # permit sender same domain
    permit_sasl_authenticated                               # permint sasl_authenticated 
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitedomain       # permit whitelisted domain
    reject                                                  # otherwise reject        

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access = hash:/etc/postfix/specialdomain
    ... other restriction ...
```

The maps

```
# /etc/postfix/specialdomain
example.com     specialdomain

# /etc/postfix/specialdomain2
example.com    OK

#/etc/postfix/whitedomain
example.net     OK
example.org     OK
```

---

#### How it works:

First postfix check if recipient listed in `/etc/postfix/specialdomain`, if yes then postfix apply the restriction defined in `specialdomain` parameter of `main.cf`.

`specialdomain` restriction has several parameters to allow email. There two `check_sender_access` to check whether the sender domain was same or already whitelisted. There is also `permit_sasl_authenticated` to permit the user authenticated by SASL. Otherwise reject it.

Comment: Masegaloeh and Tomas, thanks for detailed answers. So in fact it is possible do apply my requirement with access classes as you show in example. Also I found PolicyD more featured (including quotas, checkSPF) than postfwd. How they perform in terms of performance? Wich is better? I see postfwd is written in Perl so it's not native compiled, just interpreted?

Comment: Currently I don't have data. Benchmark it. Obviously postfix access list would be faster than postfwd and policyd